# How to automatically create tonal palettes and colors for Material3 in Android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

Googles Material3 provides a [color system](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/key-colors-tones) for design consistency throught the app.

I then looked at the [Reply](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Reply) sample app provided by Google. It has [hardcoded](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Reply/app/src/main/java/com/example/reply/ui/theme/Color.kt) all of the colors as ARGB color ints.

Is there a smarter/simpler way to create palettes using the inbuilt API? i.e. I provide provide the 3 key colours and neutral color and the Materials3 library automatically creates the respective palletes which can be used throughout the app.

Is this possible in Material3?

### Cumbersome way

```kotlin
val replyLightPrimary = Color(0xFF825500)
val replyLightOnPrimary = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
val replyLightPrimaryContainer = Color(0xFFFFDDAE)
val replyLightOnPrimaryContainer = Color(0xFF2A1800)
val replyLightSecondary = Color(0xFF6F5B40)
val replyLightOnSecondary = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
val replyLightSecondaryContainer = Color(0xFFFADEBC)
val replyLightOnSecondaryContainer = Color(0xFF271904)
val replyLightTertiary = Color(0xFF516440)
val replyLightOnTertiary = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
val replyLightTertiaryContainer = Color(0xFFD3EABC)
val replyLightOnTertiaryContainer = Color(0xFF102004)
val replyLightError = Color(0xFFBA1B1B)
val replyLightErrorContainer = Color(0xFFFFDAD4)
val replyLightOnError = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
val replyLightOnErrorContainer = Color(0xFF410001)
val replyLightBackground = Color(0xFFFCFCFC)
val replyLightOnBackground = Color(0xFF1F1B16)
val replyLightSurface = Color(0xFFFCFCFC)
val replyLightOnSurface = Color(0xFF1F1B16)
val replyLightSurfaceVariant = Color(0xFFF0E0CF)
val replyLightOnSurfaceVariant = Color(0xFF4F4539)
val replyLightOutline = Color(0xFF817567)
val replyLightInverseOnSurface = Color(0xFFF9EFE6)
val replyLightInverseSurface = Color(0xFF34302A)
val replyLightPrimaryInverse = Color(0xFFFFB945)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Material theme builder.

[Link](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder)

It will give the Color Configuration automatically.

Comment: It looks like you still need to manually input 40+ colors with the theme builder. is there anyway to use the theme builder in the app? i.e. you give 4 colors -> it gives you the 40+ colors?

Comment: I'm not sure about 40, but it gives certain colors and adjusts them itself. You export from the upper right corner

Comment: so i guess google have not made this in built into the api, accepting as answer as it seems the next best alternative.

Comment: the material.io link you provided does not seem to work. are you able to udpate?

Comment: material theme builder updated link